# when to use "take me away from here" and "get me out of here"?

Tags: phrase-usage, difference

I need to know the main difference between these two "take me away from here"   and "get me out of here" and when to use them with suitable example.
Do they carry the same meaning or i have to use them on different situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get me out of here` is more urgent, more emotional:

> Get me out of here! I can't stay in this creepy place! I'm scared to death!

Another example:

[image]

> SHARK! I need to get out of here / Somebody! Get me out of here!!!

`Take me away from here` makes me think of some lovers talking:

> Take me away from here! Let's run away and settle in a place where no one knows us...

In the situation `take me away from here` is kind of dreamy. It's not that urgent, it's not a matter of life and death.

If you want to, listen to the [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_1dBOVAV60) in which a girl is asking to take her away. It'll give you an idea and more context.

Comment: Examples are quite comprehensive.

Comment: @MudassirAwan I was happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Get me out of here. means there is danger and you want someone to get you out of that place. This implies a person will rescue you.

Take me away from here [or out of here] means: Be my guide and take me out of here. It implies a person will accompany you away from the place but the place is not necessarily dangerous, just not great.